# coldfusion tasks stop running with "interrupt task" in logs

Tags: java, coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-9

Occasionally, some of our ColdFusion 9 scheduled tasks will stop running.  The scheduler log will have a message in the format shown below.  The issue seems to be occurring a lot more frequently now and it's becoming a major issue. Within a few hour time-frame, every scheduled task on the server will have this message so that no tasks run until the CF service is restarted. We are on CF version 9,0,1,274733, java 1.6.0_17.

Can anyone explain what the cause of this may be and how to fix?  (We've tried daily server reboots which seems to be create a new issue - neo-cron.xml gets corrupted)

> Interrupt task (*script-name*) scheduled at {ts (*date-task-created*)} {ts
>   '1899-12-30 00:10:00'} null {ts '1899-12-30 23:59:00'}

Comment: Is your server really set to December 30, 1899?  I would think you want to change that specially since you are using scheduled task which rely on date/time logic.

Comment: @Miguel-F No, the server time is correct. It's current EST and it lists the correct EST time for the entry of this message in scheduler.log.  The message always has 1899-12-30 in it though.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain what the cause of this may be and how to fix? (We've tried daily server reboots which seems to be create a new issue - neo-cron.xml gets corrupted)
>
> Interrupt task (script-name) scheduled at {ts (date-task-created)} {ts '1899-12-30 00:10:00'} null {ts '1899-12-30 23:59:00'}

Have you checked your application and runtime logs? Is your request timing out? These are the things you might want to check to see whats going on.

The logs are the best way to figure out what is going on.

Thanks,